# Как проверить есть ли в migx поле с определенноым ключо равным определенному значению?

Tags: modx, migx

Хочу вывести определенный текст, если есть в `migx` поле с ключом `type` равным `one`, и если есть, то показать например цифру `2`, но не могу написать такой плейсхолдер, чтобы поставить на значение условие. Пытаюсь сделать что-то подобное:

```
[[
  [[getImageList? 
    &tvname=`e_faq_migx`
    &where=`{"type":"one"}`
    &tpl=`@CODE:[[+type]]
  `]]:is=``:then=``:else=`2`
]]
```

Но такой код не работает.

Comment: Вы объясните подробнее задачу, если в том виде как вы приводите, то `&where={"type":"one"}` отбирает только записи где type=one (это оператор фильтра), других записей не будет, и условие ниже вообще не нужно, можно сразу писать то, что должно выводиться при  type=one ибо других значений там не будет. А вот условие вы тоже неправильно написали, ` &tpl=`@CODE:[[+type:is=``:then=``:else=`2`]]` `

Answer (score 0):

```
  [[getImageList? 
    &tvname=`e_faq_migx`
    &where=`{"type:=":"one"}`
    &tpl=`resultTpl`]]
```

resultTpl:

```
result=2
```

Comment: да, но я не могу обернуть его в условие

Comment: так вызов сниппета и реализует условие, развне нет? Можете дополнительно в чанке прописать: [[+type:isequalto=`one`:then=`2`]]